# How to bind property value to view model when using custom style for Data grid columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="ToolTip"  Value="{Binding}" />
      </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
<DataGridTemplateColumn       Header="Test"
              HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CustomHeaderStyle}" 
              ToolTipService.ToolTip="Inline Tool tip" />>
```

Problem: Tool Tip is not working when using custom style.(
It is displaying Header value instead of Tool Tip value
)

Solutions Tried: Overriding and Extending and inline style is not working. 
In custom style I am trying to trigger Is mouse over event to add a Tool but I am not able to bind it's value to view model or Inline Value.

Comment: Have you tried defining the tooltip in a cell template?

Comment: Cell Template is working fine, I need tool tip  on data grid Column Header